# How to gather timing information of keystrokes using C#?

Tags: c#, keystroke, time-measurement

I want to build a simple C# Windows Form Application that gathers user's keystrokes data.

Basically, the user needs to type in a word with length 10. I want to record each key's holding time,  keydown to keydown time and keyup and keydown for adjacent keystrokes (so there are 10 + 9 + 9 = 28 measurements).

Could anyone tell me how to capture this information using text box events?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: If you have to work with this sort of thing often and you're feeling brave, you could have a look at Reactive Extensions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). That's pretty much exactly what it was invented for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events on your `TextBox`. You can get current timestamp using `DateTime.Now`.

Store your last `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events time and add measurements like this:

```
private DateTime? keyUpTime = null;
private DateTime? keyDownTime = null;

private List<double> keyDownKeyUpMeasurements = new List<double>();
private List<double> keyDownKeyDownMeasurements = new List<double>();
private List<double> keyUpKeyDownMeasurements = new List<double>();

private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime prevKeyDownTime = keyDownTime;
    keyDownTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (prevKeyDownTime != null)
    {
        keyDownKeyDownMeasurements
            .Add(keyDownTime.Subtract(prevKeyDownTime).TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    if (keyUpTime != null)
    {
        keyUpKeyDownMeasurements
            .Add(keyDownTime.Subtract(keyUpTime).TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}

private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyUpTime = DateTime.Now;
    keyDownKeyUpMeasurements
        .Add(keyUpTime.Subtract(keyDownTime).TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it can work. I'm trying to ignore bad input. Do you know how to use KeyEventArgs.KeyValue? Is "string ch = ((Char)e.KeyCode).ToString()" correct?

Comment: I doubt that cast `(Char)e.KeyCode` will work. `KeyCode` returns `Keys` enum  value. What are you trying to achieve? To filter specific characters you can use something like `e.KeyCode != Keys.A`.

Comment: The user's input should be a fixed words with length of 10 (like "abcdefghij"). So that I need to check whether the user press the right key. I don't want to use a long condition like if(e.KeyCode!=keys.A && e.KeyCode!=Keys.B &&......)

Comment: You can use something like `bool stringIsAllLetters = yourString.All(c => Char.IsLetter(c));`.